# Preview of a Uploaded PDF and Image File

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a Document Uploading grid view Page.

I want to Preview that uploaded PDF and image in other new tab.

I have done Image view.
How will I view Uploaded PDf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an Template field in your Gridview like this

```
<ItemTemplate>                
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnView" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("AttachmentPath") %>' OnClick="lnkbtnView_Click" runat="server">View</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

then add another page for viewing pdf like this

add an `iframe` like this

```
 <iframe id="pdfiframe" name="pdfiframe" runat="server" width="100%" Height="700px" />
```

then on your first page on template click write code like this

```
protected void lnkbtnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
                string pathh = "~\\Documents\\" + ((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument).ToString();
               //suppose your all pdf are in document folder here you can give your foldername
                Session["pdf"] = pathh;

                Response.Write("<script> window.open('" + "DocumentViewerPage.aspx" + "','_blank','toolbar = yes, scrollbars = yes, resizable = yes, top = 30, left = 100, width = 1160, height = 600'); </script>");
    }
```

then on page load of new tab page   whom you want to Preview

```
// on any button click or page load


pdfiframe.Attributes["src"] =Session["pdf"].ToString(); //Here you need to pass the source of that file
```

Comment: can you tell me mvc code and how it will show PDF and image same file browsing?

Comment: Hook i have given the way how you can achieve that you just need to implement it in your way

Comment: just do the same for that it will ask you to download that excel file then this will also show you the excel file